# How can I scale up the font size of just the content in a web page?

Tags: browser, browser-addons, zoom, browsing

I'm a Firefox user with a giant screen (i.e. tiny pixels) and I like to zoom in on pages to get a bigger font for reading articles. The problem is, hitting control-plus zooms in the whole page, making all images look gross. Is there a trick or plugin or something for just bumping the font size on "content-like" areas of the page?

Is something like this available in any other browser?

Comment: PS: I already know and love and use Readability, but sometimes I just want to bump the font size in-page rather than stripping out all but the content. Maybe I'm just being picky :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My version of Firefox (3.6.13) has the option View > Zoom > Zoom Text Only

When I select this option then hold down the CTRL key and roll the mouse scroll wheel, it zooms only the text portion of the page.

I just checked in IE8 and it has a View > Text Size option though it doesn't seem to have quite the same range for enlarging the text.

Comment: Cool, hadn't thought to look for that actually. Ideally this would only apply to the 'content' area of a page but that's a very difficult thing to heuristically look for... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are several great [zoom addons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=zoom&cat=all&x=0&y=0) for Firefox - I think you'll like [Zoom Page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/zoom-page/)